# How to use Microsoft.PointOfService version 1.12 in .NET framework 4.5 project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, printing, pos-for-.net

I have problem with Microsoft.PointOfService 1.12. I created project using .NET framework 4.5, and I use Microsoft.PointOfService version 1.12. I get error like

> The type initializer for
>   'Microsoft.PointOfService.Management.Explorer' threw an exception.

I follow [this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9611438/the-type-initializer-for-microsoft-pointofservice-management-explorer-threw-an). But it's not success. And I get more error like

> Dynamic operations can only be performed in homogenous AppDomain.

Follow [this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16157279/dynamic-operations-can-only-be-performed-in-homogenous-appdomain-error-while-l), I must disable **legacyCasPolicy** but it's same mean I can not use Microsoft.PointOfService 1.12 in .NET framework 4.5.

Do you have any ideas to solve this problem?